# apex:column header value not displaying with apex:inputField

Tags: visualforce, column

[The docs for `<apex:column />`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_column.htm) states that the default behavior of the headerValue displays the field label when using an `<apex:inputField/>` or an `<apex:outputField/>` tag.

> Note also that specifying a value for this attribute overrides the default header label that appears if you use an inputField or outputField in the column body.

However the header value is blank when I do so.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!productsToInsert}" var="p" id="orderItemTable" >
    <apex:column>
        <apex:inputField value="{!p.Name}" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column>
        <apex:inputField value="{!p.Family}">
    </apex:inputField>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column>
        <apex:inputField value="{!p.isActive}" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column >
        <apex:inputField value="{!p.Initial_Inventory__c}" />
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

How is this supposed to work with nesting inputFields inside the Apex Column body?

Comment: Yeah, the docs have the same text for the `headerValue` attribute and the `facet` attribute.  If it's not displaying a label it seems like it may be a bug.  Does it work when you use `outputField` or when you use the `value` attribute?

Comment: @IllusiveBrian when I use the `value` attribute on the column it shows a label, but for this case I want input from the User. Specifying the `value` attribute only displays the data. I think this is a bug too, or just bad documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misread the documentation.

From [apex:column docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_column.htm)

> Note that if you specify an sObject field as the value attribute for an , the associated label for that field is used as the column header by default.

It's clear that we don't need to supply `headerValue` when we set the `value` attribute of `apex:column`. However, when we add tags like `apex:inputField` or `apex:outputField`, we need to supply `headerValue` which can be done as follows without actually hardcoding the label text.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!productsToInsert}" var="p" id="orderItemTable" >
    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Product2.Fields.Name.Label}">
        <apex:inputField value="{!p.Name}" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Product2.Fields.Family.Label}">
        <apex:inputField value="{!p.Family}" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Product2.Fields.IsActive.Label}">
        <apex:inputField value="{!p.IsActive}" />
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

We can use `$ObjectType` global merge field to access object/field schema in Visualforce.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did read that section, but on the field description for `headerValue` it states
 

"The text that should be displayed in the column header. If you specify a value for this attribute, you cannot use the column's header facet. Note also that specifying a value for this attribute overrides the default header label that appears if you use an inputField or outputField in the column body."

In the column body it should use the inputField's field label to generate the header value. But this works, thank you @jagmohan

Comment: I edited the question that highlights the specific note that says it should use the inputField's label.

Comment: @Programatic Please accept the answer if that's what helped you work around the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I will keep this open for now. Your answer is a work around but does not answer the question.